# How to add the script to the top of script list in Joomla 2.5

Tags: php, joomla

I use `$doc->addScript` in top of template file to add my script (and `jquery`) in a head, but components are added their scripts before.

Can I control this output queue?

Answer (score 1):

*I'm writing this for Joomla 3.3.x*

**Unfortunatly this cannot be done without either hacking core-files (don't do that!!) or use an own implementation for javascript-adding.**

If you look into [joomlaroot]\libraries\joomla\document\document.php -> line 446, where the function addScript is defined, you will see, that the _scripts-Array in JDocument is an assoc. Array where the key is the url to the script.

If you don't want to rewrite the joomla-methods that add a script and every installed extension in your system, you should add your javascripts in the template after < jdoc:include type="head" >.

[You could write a system-plugin](http://docs.joomla.org/Plugin), that uses the event "[onBeforeCompileHead](http://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events/System#onBeforeCompileHead)" to reorder the document-scripts, but i think that would be too much.

I don't know, why joomla does not simply use a sort-attribute in addScript(), that would be so needed. Also Script-Dependencies could be realised. Even Wordpress can do that.

**EDIT**: What you COULD do, is use [JDocument::addCustomTag()](http://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JDocumentHTML.html#method_addCustomTag) to add your scripts AFTER the joomla-scripts. Because the custom-tags are rendered after all the scripts. Although this does not affect the order of scripts already loaded by other components.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use a foreach loop for that.

For Joomla 2.5: In your templates index.php add the following if you want to prepend a script, example shows the inclusion of jquery:

```
$headData = $this->getHeadData();
reset($headData['scripts']);
$newHeadData = $headData['scripts'];
$jquery = array('http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js' => array('mime' => 'text/javascript', 'defer' => FALSE, 'async' => FALSE));
$newHeadData = $jquery + $newHeadData;
//$some_other_script = array("path-to-your-script" => array('mime' => 'text/javascript', 'defer' => FALSE, 'async' => FALSE));
//$newHeadData = $some_other_script + $newHeadData;
$headData['scripts'] = $newHeadData;
$this->setHeadData($headData);
```

For Joomla 3.3: This might work in the same way as for Joomla 2.5 as the functions getHeadData() and setHeadData() are still present. See the API documentation: http://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JDocumentHTML.html

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to modify your template's `index.php` file. The following includes [Joomla's head section](http://docs.joomla.org/Jdoc_statements#Head):

```
<jdoc:include type="head"/>
```

Simply move `$doc->addScript` after this (or before it) to set which loads first. Files load top to bottom, so whatever is on top will load first.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done, but it's a bit tricky.The following code is based on https://gist.github.com/AmyStephen/5971447

```
$head = JFactory::getDocument()->getHeadData();
$scripts = $head['scripts'];
$newScripts = array();

foreach ($scripts as $key => $value)
{
   if (/**  test to reorder the scripts */) 
   {
        $newScripts[$key] = $value;
    }
 }            

 $head['scripts'] = $newScripts;
 JFactory::getDocument()->setHeadData($head);
```

In other words, the scripts are stored as an array and you need to reorder it.